# Writing data (dynamically) to an external drive

Tags: pi-3, hard-drive

I am attempting to gather a day's worth of thermal data from a thermal camera. This obviously will need more data than the sd card can handle so I have a 1 TB hard drive I have setup using ntfs-3g (with exec option).

When I run my script and either fprintf redirect (./script > file.txt) the output to a location on the HD the file is created, but it is always empty.

Running ./script sends the expected thermal data to the terminal. I have looked all over the internet for similar problems, but I'm not finding them. What have I messed up here?

### Added Information:

My data gathering program does not end, I kill it with CTRL-C.

If I wait long enough (a minute or so) files with multiples of 4096 bytes (the block size of the disc, confirmed by "blockdev --getbsz /dev/sda1") will begin to appear.

Some of the initial tests only waited ~5 to 10 seconds with the purpose of making sure the process was working. From what I can tell, when I kill the process with control C, any pending writes are also killed.

The "disc queue" does not write out to disk until it hits a block. So when my script runs for a day, I will probably lose the last minute of data, but that is alright.

I could look into reformatting the disc to a smaller block size, but honestly losing one minute out of around 10 hours of data does not concern me.

Comment: run `dmesg` ... any errors regarding the drive?

Comment: Also use >> to append to the file rather than > which overwrites (unless you are actually planning to write a massive file each time).

Comment: Why would you use NTFS rather than exFAT? What do you mean by *”thermal data”*? Are they individual JPEGs or video? Do you ever flush or sync in your program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register `Signal Handlers` in your program in order to catch the `ctrl-c` and flush all the buffers/files opened by your program and script.

### Edit Following Additional Information

Killing a program with `ctrl-c` will likely cause data truncation. This is actually implementation dependent and not always consistent between linux systems (some will `flush` all buffers on `exit`). You need to change your design to shutdown gracefully.

Some Background:: There are actually Two Buffers

1. Userspace Buffer, when a file is opened by a program you get a kernel provided buffer, this is where data from `fprintf` goes.
2. Kernel Disk Cache, kernel caches file in memory before writing to disk.

`sync` (or `fsync`)  is used to for #2 , `flush` is used for #1.

> Note: `close` is guaranteed to issue `flush`, but `exit` is not guaranteed to `close` all open files.

When you interrupt the program, you lose unwritten data in the Userspace buffer, data already written to the kernel (`flush`ed) may be cached but won't be lost.

However, if pull the  power from your raspberry PI before performing an `sync` some data may be lost on reboot.

#### Install a Signal handler

If this is a program or script you have written yourself, you should install a `signal handler` , in order to "react" to the `ctrl-c` you have issued.

You can install signal handler to `catch` `SIGINT (ctrl-c)` and issue `flush`, `fsync` and `sync` commands

Signal Handlers can be used in all major programming languages and shell scripts.

In the context of an application, your signal handler would issue the command `flush` or `close` to any open streams/files followed by an `fsync` per open file for good measure.

In the context of a shell script, your signal handler should gracefully close the running process, and maybe a `sync` to make sure no data is lost on reboot.

### Other things to try

1. In order to better diagnose your issue you run

   `./script &> file.txt`

   This will cover the unusual case that your script is writing to `stderr` and not `stdout`, just to be sure its not something so trivial
2. To verify FS and Driver are functioning

   `echo test > file.txt`
3. Sometimes kernel buffering and driver options will result in extended delays for writes to disk drives. Use `sync` to force kernel to flush filesystem caches

   `./script > file.txt ; sync`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! a few interesting things: the first bullet point worked, I inserted an error, and it made the appropriate file. The second bullet point worked as well. However the third still results in an empty file. I know my script generates output, as I sanity check multiple times that it is, but I still cannot write it to the disk for some reason.

Comment: Correction: it works occasionally, but not often. (1 in 10 times or so)

Comment: It seems like short tests fail more often - is it possible these small writes simply get removed from the "write queue" when the process requesting the write is killed before they go out to disk?